# cropping figure using trim and clip options with Overleaf vs Texpad

Tags: graphics, texpad

As you can see in my example, I try to include a vector pdf graphic and crop away its title (I want to put the info that is written in the title into the caption). When I do this using the trim={} and clip option, I get the expected result in Overleaf. However, if I do the exact same thing in Texpad, the title remains in the pdf figure and the figure is shifted upwards, so that it now overlaps with the text (see screenshot). When doing the same thing with a .jpeg version of the graphics, it suddenly works.

I am using Texpad on MacOS 10.15.7 and I rely on the interal compiler that outputs no error messages and has never made me any trouble so far, apart from this problem.

Here is the example (I didn't manage to upload the vector pdf, just use any pdf e.g. with text only and any raster jpg, otherwise please instruct me how to upload vector graphics here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 0.6cm},clip,width=0.7\textwidth]{test.jpg}
\includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 0.6cm},clip,width=0.7\textwidth]{test.pdf}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Here is the output from overleaf:
[image]

And here it is from Texpad:
[image]

Edit: Here is the log from Texpad:

```
This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode (preloaded format=latex 2020.7.30)  3 JAN 2021 14:19
**
(MinimumExample.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
(t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
(utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1
(t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   ...
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1
(ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   ...
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS
(omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   ...
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   ...
)) (lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/01/04 3.16 The Babel package
(switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel switching mechanism
) (english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
(babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel common definitions
(switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel switching mechanism
)
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
(txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count88
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)) (graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
) (graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2018/05/3 Graphics configuration of TexpadTeX
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: texpadtex.def on input line 99.
(texpadtex.def
File: texpadtex.def 2017/10/21 v2.0
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen104
\Gin@req@width=\dimen105
) (lipsum.sty
Package: lipsum 2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\c@lips@count=\count89
)
No file MinimumExample.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 8.
(t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
File: test.jpg Graphic file (type vvtimg)
<test.jpg>
File: test.pdf Graphic file (type vvtimg)
<test.pdf> [1

] (MinimumExample.aux) )


This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode (preloaded format=latex 2020.7.30)  3 JAN 2021 14:19
**
(MinimumExample.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
(t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
(utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1
(t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   ...
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1
(ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   ...
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS
(omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   ...
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   ...
)) (lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/01/04 3.16 The Babel package
(switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel switching mechanism
) (english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
(babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel common definitions
(switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel switching mechanism
)
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
(txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count88
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)) (graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
) (graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2018/05/3 Graphics configuration of TexpadTeX
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: texpadtex.def on input line 99.
(texpadtex.def
File: texpadtex.def 2017/10/21 v2.0
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen104
\Gin@req@width=\dimen105
) (lipsum.sty
Package: lipsum 2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\c@lips@count=\count89
) (MinimumExample.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 8.
(t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
File: test.jpg Graphic file (type vvtimg)
<test.jpg>
File: test.pdf Graphic file (type vvtimg)
<test.pdf> [1

] (MinimumExample.aux) )
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which version of `graphicx` do you use, and which LaTeX distribution and version (presumably some version of MacTeX?)? Could you edit (the relevant parts of) your `.log` file into your question?

Comment: I tried to add the log from Texpad (I had to shorten repeated lines). As I tried to point out, I am using the interal typesetter of Texpad which up to this point has worked flawlessly for me. I have now installed MacTex which temporarily solves the issue for me (same as using Overlaf). I don't want to have TeX installed permanently though, that's the whole point of using Texpad for me.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that Texpad has it's own compiler implementation. Maybe it is a problem with the editor preview, you could try opening the document with another pdf viewer to see if the problem is also present there. You could also consider asking Texpad support about this at http://support.texpad.com/discussion/new.